# How to solve second order using the first order code?

Tags: matlab

I have solved  a ODE first order equation using matlab. The equation is $$y' = t^2$$. Now I want to solve second order differential equation  using the same code. y''(x) = -y,  where  $y(0) =1$ and $y'(x=0) = 0$.

How to change the below code so i can find the value of y? What I tried is that, i made it to a first order differential equation, but I'm confused how to  change the code.

```
clc;                                               % Clears the screen
clear all;

h=0.2;                                             % step size
x = 0:h:1;                                         % Calculates upto y(3)
y = zeros(1,length(x)); 
y(1) = 1;                                          % initial condition
F_x = @(t) t.^2;                    % change the function as you desire

for i=1:(length(x)-1)                              % calculation loop
    k_1 = F_x(x(i));
    k_2 = F_x(x(i)+0.5*h);
    k_3 = F_x((x(i)+0.5*h));
    k_4 = F_x((x(i)+h));

    y(i+1) = y(i) + (1/6)*(k_1+2*k_2+2*k_3+k_4)*h;  % main equation
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you want to split your 2nd order ODE to 2 1st order ODE. So your system of equations is

y' = u

u' = -y

where

y(0)=1

u(0)=0

Therefore, we can modify your program

[image: Runga-Kutta]

```
function StackOverflow
close all
set(groot,'defaultLineLineWidth',3)

dx=pi/100;
x = (0:dx:2*pi)';
N = length(x);

Y = nan(size(x,1),2);
Y(1,:) = [1, 0];

F = { @(x,y)  y(2) , @(x,y) -y(1) };

for i=1:N-1                              % calculation loop
    k_1 = cellfun(@(f) f(x(i)         , Y(i,:))              , F);
    k_2 = cellfun(@(f) f(x(i) + 0.5*dx, Y(i,:) + 0.5*dx*k_1) , F);
    k_3 = cellfun(@(f) f(x(i) + 0.5*dx, Y(i,:) + 0.5*dx*k_2) , F);
    k_4 = cellfun(@(f) f(x(i) +     dx, Y(i,:) +     dx*k_3) , F);

    Y(i+1,:) = Y(i,:) + (dx/6)*(k_1+2*k_2+2*k_3+k_4);  % main equation
end

y = Y(:,1);
u = Y(:,2);

figure(1)
set(gcf, 'units', 'normalized')

subplot(2,1,1)
plot(x , y , '--', x, cos(x), ':')
axis('tight')
set(gca,'fontsize',14, 'Position',[0.12 0.55 0.84 0.4])
xticks(0:pi/2:2*pi)
xticklabels({})
ylabel('$y(x)=\cos(x)$', 'Interpreter', 'latex')


subplot(2,1,2)
plot(x , u, '--', x, -sin(x), ':')
set(gca,'fontsize',14, 'Position',[0.12 0.1 0.84 0.4])
axis('tight')
xticks(0:pi/2:2*pi)
xticklabels({'0', '\pi/2', '\pi', '3\pi/2', '2\pi'})

xlabel('x', 'Interpreter', 'latex')
ylabel('$y''(x)=-\sin(x)$', 'Interpreter', 'latex')

end
```

Comment: Why `cellfun`?  A simple anonymous function like `F = @(x,y)  [y(2); -y(1)];` (like the standard ODE suite interface) should suffice and be faster.